# What is this mysterious *green square* on my Content Editor?

Tags: content-editor

I was wondering if anyone knows what is this mysterious little green square on my Content Editor.

[image]

I've never seen any mention to it on the official documentation as far as I can remember.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That is an indicator of the outcome of any [field](https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2011/05/09/using-sitecore-field-validators/) or item validators on the currently-loaded item.

- **Green** = All validators are valid
- **Yellow** = At least one validator is in warning state
- **Red** = At least one validator is in error state (validation is failing)

Comment: Just as additional help, here is the user documentation on validating items: https://doc.sitecore.com/users/91/sitecore-experience-platform/en/validate-an-item.html#UUID-d9e7ff34-3400-f768-d7ea-73d20c158ad6_id__Validate_an_item